# Fl_chart | Flutter

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

currently I'm facing error in Fl_chart flutter. In part of my code I insert bottomTitles: SideTitles but system shown error ["**The argument type 'SideTitles' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AxisTitles**'.].

```
       `bottomTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  rotateAngle:
                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 400 ? -45 : -90,
                  reservedSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 500
                      ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03
                      : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
                  getTitles: (value) {
                    final hour = value.toInt();

                    final formattedHour =
                        (hour % 12 == 0) ? '12' : (hour % 12).toString();
                    final period = (hour < 12) ? 'AM' : 'PM';

                    if (formattedHour + period == previousHour) {
                      return '';
                    }
                    // Store the current title to check for duplicates in the next iteration
                    previousHour = formattedHour + period;

                    return '$formattedHour $period';
                  },
                ),`
```

Error Detail As Below:

[image]

I try change the SideTitles into AxisTitles system pop out another 4 Errors(refer as below), after that I search in chatGPT say that below parameters only able to use in SideTitles & advice me seek advice in library comunity.

Can anyone Help me in this issue? Thank you in advance!

```
-[**"The named parameter 'rotateAngle' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'rotateAngle'."**] 

-[**"The named parameter 'getTitles' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'getTitles'."**] 

-[**"The named parameter 'showTitles' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'showTitles'."**]

-[**"The named parameter 'reservedSize' isn't defined.\nTry correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'reservedSize'."**]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, botomTiles expects an `AxisTitle`, so you should wrap your `SideTitle` with an `AxisTitle`:

```
bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
      sideTitles: SideTitles(
        ....
      ),
    ),
```

And for the other errors it seems SideTitles doesn't use those parameters anymore:

```
  /// Determines showing or hiding this side titles
  final bool showTitles;

  /// You can override it to pass your custom widget to show in each axis value
  /// We recommend you to use [SideTitleWidget].
  final GetTitleWidgetFunction getTitlesWidget;

  /// It determines the maximum space that your titles need,
  /// (All titles will stretch using this value)
  final double reservedSize;

  /// Texts are showing with provided [interval]. If you don't provide anything,
  /// we try to find a suitable value to set as [interval] under the hood.
  final double? interval;
```

Check the last version of fi_chart and compare with yours

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your SideTitles in an AxisTitles. Try like below code. Also, check the Latest Version for some changes.

```
bottomTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: getBottomTitles),

Widget getBottomTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
{
  final hour = value.toInt();

  final formattedHour = (hour % 12 == 0) ? '12' : (hour % 12).toString();
  final period = (hour < 12) ? 'AM' : 'PM';

  if (formattedHour + period == previousHour) {
    return const Text('');
  }
  // Store the current title to check for duplicates in the next iteration
  previousHour = formattedHour + period;
}
return Text('$formattedHour $period');
```

}